# GridLayout items size is not equal to each other

Tags: qml

I have got `Qt` class which is subclass of `QQuickImageProvider` here is `requestPixmap` function realization:

```
QPixmap MyImageProvider::requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize       
    &requestedSize){
    int width = 100;
        int height = 50;

        if (size)
            *size = QSize(width, height);
        QPixmap pixmap(requestedSize.width() > 0 ? requestedSize.width() : width,
                       requestedSize.height() > 0 ? requestedSize.height() : height);
        pixmap.fill(QColor(id).rgba());

        return pixmap;
 }
```

In `qml` I have `GridLayout` which items is came from image provider. By clicking buttons I can show 1, 2 or 4 items.  Here is `qml` file:

```
 import QtQuick 2.3
 import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
 import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
 import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1
 import QtQuick.Window 2.2

 Window{
     id: root
     title: "settings"
     modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
     flags: Qt.Dialog
     minimumHeight: 700
     minimumWidth: 700
     maximumHeight: 700
     maximumWidth: 700
     ColumnLayout{
          id: columnLayout
          anchors.fill: parent
          RowLayout{
              ExclusiveGroup{id: exgroup}
              Button{
                  text: "1x1"
                  checkable: true
                  checked: true
                  Layout.minimumWidth: 100
                  Layout.minimumHeight: 100
                  exclusiveGroup: exgroup
                  onCheckedChanged: {
                      if(checked===true){
                      grid.columns=1
                      grid.rows=1
                      im1.visible = true
                      im2.visible = false
                      im3.visible = false
                      im4.visible = false
                      im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/yellow"
                }
            }
            }

        Button{
            text: "1x2"
            checkable: true
            checked: false
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
            exclusiveGroup: exgroup
            onCheckedChanged: {
                if(checked===true){
                    grid.columns=1
                    grid.rows=2
                    im1.visible = true
                    im2.visible = true
                    im3.visible = false
                    im4.visible = false
                    im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/red"
                    im2.source = "image://plotPixmap/black"


                }
            }
        }
        Button{
            text: "2x1"
            checkable: true
            checked: false
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
            exclusiveGroup: exgroup
            onCheckedChanged: {
                if(checked===true){
                    grid.columns=2
                    grid.rows=1
                    im1.visible = true
                    im2.visible = true
                    im3.visible = false
                    im4.visible = false
                    im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/blue"
                    im2.source = "image://plotPixmap/green"

                }
            }
        }
        Button{
            text: "2x2"
            checkable: true
            checked: false
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
            exclusiveGroup: exgroup
            onCheckedChanged: {
                if(checked===true){
                    grid.columns=2
                    grid.rows=2
                    im1.visible = true
                    im2.visible = true
                    im3.visible = true
                    im4.visible = true
                    im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/blue"
                    im2.source = "image://plotPixmap/green"
                    im3.source = "image://plotPixmap/black"
                    im4.source = "image://plotPixmap/red"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Image{
            id: im1
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            sourceSize.height: height
            sourceSize.width: width
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
        }
        Image{
            id: im2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            sourceSize.height: height
            sourceSize.width: width
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
        }
        Image{
            id: im3
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            sourceSize.height: height
            sourceSize.width: width
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
        }
        Image{
            id: im4
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            sourceSize.height: height
            sourceSize.width: width
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

In c++ main:

```
engine->addImageProvider(QLatin1String("plotPixmap"), new MyImageProvider());
```

Everything works but when I press buttons several times size of bottom images became smaller and smaller. How to fix size o images? I want all images to be the same size and they shuld fill all space under buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the result of the interactions between the different `fillHeight`/`fillwidth` set. As stated in the documentation:

> The fillWidth and fillHeight properties can either be true or false.
>   If it is false, the item's size will be fixed to its preferred size.
>   Otherwise, it will grow or shrink **between its minimum and maximum size**
>   as the layout is resized.

In this case, the minimum width is not set for the four images. Hence, as the `GridLayout` structure changes, according to the pressed button, the constraints are recalculated and in certain patterns (e.g. `2x1 -> 1x1 -> 2x1`) the recalculated widths/heights gives more space to the first images (according to the `flow`). To fix the problem you should ensure that the minimum width/height are set on each image, i.e. `Layout.minimumWidth` and `Layout.minimumHeight` attached properties has the correct values.

Directly set such values in the code results in binding loops. Again from the documentation:

> Note: It is not recommended to have bindings to the x, y, width, or
>   height properties of items in a layout, since this would conflict with
>   the goal of the Layout, and also cause **binding loops**.

To avoid the problem, the `GridLayout` is embeded in an `Item` which fills the `ColumnLayout` in place of the `GridLayout` itself. Size constraints are then safely applied to the images. Here is the final code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    id: root
    title: "settings"
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    minimumHeight: 700
    minimumWidth: 700
    maximumHeight: 700
    maximumWidth: 700
    visible:  true

    ColumnLayout{
        id: columnLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        RowLayout{
            ExclusiveGroup{id: exgroup}
            Button{
                text: "1x1"
                checkable: true
                checked: true
                Layout.minimumWidth: 100
                Layout.minimumHeight: 100
                exclusiveGroup: exgroup
                onCheckedChanged: {
                    if(checked){
                        grid.columns = grid.rows = 1
                        im1.visible = true
                        im2.visible = im3.visible = im4.visible = false
                        im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/yellow"
                    }
                }
            }

            Button{
                text: "1x2"
                checkable: true
                checked: false
                Layout.minimumWidth: 100
                Layout.minimumHeight: 100
                exclusiveGroup: exgroup
                onCheckedChanged: {
                    if(checked){
                        grid.columns = 1
                        grid.rows = 2
                        im1.visible = im2.visible = true
                        im3.visible = im4.visible = false
                        im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/red"
                        im2.source = "image://plotPixmap/black"
                    }
                }
            }
            Button{
                text: "2x1"
                checkable: true
                checked: false
                Layout.minimumWidth: 100
                Layout.minimumHeight: 100
                exclusiveGroup: exgroup
                onCheckedChanged: {
                    if(checked){
                        grid.columns = 2
                        grid.rows = 1
                        im1.visible = im2.visible = true
                        im3.visible = im4.visible = false
                        im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/blue"
                        im2.source = "image://plotPixmap/green"

                    }
                }
            }
            Button{
                text: "2x2"
                checkable: true
                checked: false
                Layout.minimumWidth: 100
                Layout.minimumHeight: 100
                exclusiveGroup: exgroup
                onCheckedChanged: {
                    if(checked){
                        grid.columns = grid.rows = 2
                        im1.visible = im2.visible = im3.visible = im4.visible = true
                        im1.source = "image://plotPixmap/blue"
                        im2.source = "image://plotPixmap/green"
                        im3.source = "image://plotPixmap/black"
                        im4.source = "image://plotPixmap/red"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Item {      // layout ensure to fill the available space
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            GridLayout {
                id: grid
                anchors.fill: parent     // anchor to the available space

                Image{
                    id: im1
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.minimumWidth: grid.width / 2      // constraint to the min width
                    Layout.minimumHeight:  grid.height / 2   // constraint to the min height
                    Layout.rowSpan: 1
                    Layout.columnSpan: 1
                }
                Image{
                    id: im2
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.minimumWidth: grid.width / 2     // constraint to the min width
                    Layout.minimumHeight:  grid.height / 2  // constraint to the min height
                    Layout.rowSpan: 1
                    Layout.columnSpan: 1
                }
                Image{
                    id: im3
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.minimumWidth: grid.width / 2     // constraint to the min width
                    Layout.minimumHeight:  grid.height / 2  // constraint to the min height
                    Layout.rowSpan: 1
                    Layout.columnSpan: 1
                }
                Image{
                    id: im4
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.minimumWidth: grid.width / 2     // constraint to the min width
                    Layout.minimumHeight:  grid.height / 2  // constraint to the min height
                    Layout.rowSpan: 1
                    Layout.columnSpan: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```